# Multithreading and structs with ZeroMQ

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures, zeromq, void-pointers

I'm trying to figure out exactly why I can't successfully pass a struct through zthread_fork using ZeroMQ.

The [documentation](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zthread) for zthread_fork says that it accepts the following as arguments:

```
zthread_fork (zctx_t *ctx, zthread_attached_fn *thread_fn, void *args);
```

Here's my function call:

```
void *client = zthread_fork ( ctx, client_thread, (void *)&my_struct );
```

Here's my function prototype:

```
static void client_thread ( zctx_t *ctx, void *args )
```

It seems fairly simple to me - create a struct and pass a (void *) pointer to zthread_fork(), which client_thread is expecting.

I get a set of error messages when I compile:

```
$gcc ft_test3_verbose.c -o ft_test3_verbose -L/usr/local/lib -lczmq > err_out
ft_test3_verbose.c: In function ‘client_thread’:
ft_test3_verbose.c:18:31: error: invalid initializer
 struct arg_struct input = (struct arg_struct *)args;
                           ^
ft_test3_verbose.c:20:46: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct arg_struct’)
 printf( "Here's some stuff: %d \n", input->data );
                                          ^
ft_test3_verbose.c:21:53: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct arg_struct’)
 printf( "Here's a different stuff: %s \n", input->test_str );
                                                 ^
ft_test3_verbose.c: In function ‘main’:
ft_test3_verbose.c:123:29: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zthread_fork’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     zthread_fork ( ctx, client_thread, (void *)&my_struct );
                         ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/czmq_library.h:175:0,
             from /usr/local/include/czmq.h:30,
             from ft_test3_verbose.c:2:
/usr/local/include/zthread.h:39:5: note: expected ‘void (*)(void *, zctx_t *, void *) {aka void (*)(void *, struct _zctx_t *, void *)}’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(zctx_t *, void *) {aka void (*)(struct _zctx_t *, void *)}’
     zthread_fork (zctx_t *ctx, zthread_attached_fn *thread_fn, void *args);
     ^
```

Here's my code (I haven't included the server_thread() function because it's identical to the example server_thread() from the [ZMQ FileIO example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:fileio3):

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <czmq.h>
#define CHUNK_SIZE 250000
#define PIPELINE 10

struct arg_struct {
    int data;
char *test_str;

};

static void client_thread ( zctx_t *ctx, void *args )
{
    void *pipe = NULL;
    void *dealer = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsocket_connect (dealer, "tcp://127.0.0.1:6000");

    struct arg_struct input = (struct arg_struct *)args;

    printf( "Here's some stuff: %d \n", input->data );
    printf( "Here's a different stuff: %s \n", input->test_str );
    zstr_send( pipe, "OK" );
}

int main (void)
{
    zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new (); 

    struct arg_struct my_struct = { 0, "testing" };

    zthread_fork (ctx, server_thread, NULL);
    void *client = 
        zthread_fork ( ctx, client_thread, (void *)&my_struct );
    char *string = zstr_recv (client);
    free (string);
    zctx_destroy (&ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Help is much appreciated

Comment: There are structs and there are pointers to structs. The thread code needs to use a pointer, since that's what you're passing from `main`. In other words, `struct arg_struct input` needs to be `struct arg_struct *input`. Note the `*`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! Fixed.